# Apache RewriteRule fails on question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

We had a typo when creating URLs, so

```
/wasserh?hne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-dg11040-e+1281
```

should be redirected to

```
/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-dg11040-e+1281
```

the .htaccess starts with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kull-design.com$1 [R,L=301]

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteRule   (.*) index.php [L]
RewriteRule  ^eng/deu index.php
```

and normally sth like this works

```
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/wasserhaehne-aus-messing/ https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhahn-classic/wasserhahn-13cm-40-593+631
```

but this fails

```
RewriteRule /wasserh?hne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-dg11040-e+1281 https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-dg11040-e+1281
```

I tried to escape the ?, but that doesn't help. I suspect that the part after the ? is seen as query string, so I attempted

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} hne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-kurz-dg11040m+1277
RewriteRule ^/wasserh https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-kurz-dg11040m+1277 [R=301,L]
```

but that doesn't do the trick. There are similar questions, but they deal with real query strings.

**Update**:

I tested PanamaJacks solution using [htaccess.madewithlove.be](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). It seems any url starting with wasserh is redirected to the same product. So i tried this instead

```
https://www.kull-design.com/wasserh?hne/wasserhahn-gebogen-dg110h76870+1295

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hne/wasserhahn-gebogen-dg11010+1295
RewriteRule ^wasserh(.*)$ https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-gebogen-dg11010+1295 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't match the condition. Again escaping - or + has no effect.

**Update**:
Note that you have to put these redirects before the RewriteRule, that sends anything to index.php or it won't work in spite of the rewrite-conditions being correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this should work kinda. Give this rule a try and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^wasserh(.*)$ https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-kurz-dg11040m+1277? [R=301,L]
```

Edit:

Then just try matching part of it that is unique to that URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hne(.+)1281$
RewriteRule ^wasserh(.*)$ https://www.kull-design.com/wasserhaehne/wasserhahn-1-2-zoll-kurz-dg11040m+1277? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See my update and see if that helps. Also why can't you just correct the URL?